# XSL Transformation Choose only the elements under the root tag without child nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a XML file like following 
and i want to select only the rootelements and no child elements with a match template.
Can somebody help me how to write a match template which only selects the root elements from it ?
Thanks for your help.

```
<root>
<child1>
<element1>Valule</element1>
<element2>Value</element2>
</child1>
<child2>
<element1>Value</element1>
<element2>Value</element2>
</child2>
<rootelement1>rootval1</rootelement1>
<rootelement2>rootval2</rootelement2>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select only the elements under the root tag without child elements, you can do the following

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/*[not(*)]" />
```

Or, if you were currently positioned on the **root** element, it would be simplified to the following:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(*)]" />
```

So, for example, with the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/root">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(*)]" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to you sample XML, the following is returned

```
<rootelement1>rootval1</rootelement1>
<rootelement2>rootval2</rootelement2>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, Thats exactly what i wanted to do.